# JPA Query: join a subquery with grouping condition

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I have an entity that represents a change event for a specific object. Something like:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    private String eventId;
    private String objectId;
    private Instant creationDate;
    // other fields, getters, setters
}
```

There might be several event objects for a specific `objectId`.

Now **I need to query all latest events for a each `objectId`** (those that have max `creationDate` groping by `objectId`) .

If it was pure SQL I would write the following query:

```
SELECT event.*
FROM
  event event
  JOIN (
         SELECT
           e.object_id          object_id,
           MAX(e.creation_date) last_date
         FROM event e
         GROUP BY e.object_id
       ) latest_event
    ON latest_event.object_id = event.object_id
       AND event.creation_date = latest_event.last_date
```

But the similar join unfortunately doesn't work in JPA query.

**Question:** How to join a subquery in a JPA query?

Using a native query is not an option in my case, because I use Spring Data JPA repository with pagination functionality which doesn't work for native queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query( 
    value = "SELECT e FROM Event e " + 
            "WHERE e.creationDate = " +
            "(SELECT max(e2.creationDate) FROM Event e2 " + 
            "WHERE e2.objectId = e.objectId)"
)
```

Comment: This won't work. You ignore `objectId ` in the subquery which means that the max date you calculate has no relation to the object.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota each row has a max date by own objectId select by this query

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Somehow I thought that the subquery ends at the third line of the query. Let me check how it works.

Comment: if max creation date are equal for 2 objectIds this won't work.

Comment: @Rohit if we have two `objectId` and both has a Y `creationDate' and Y is `max creationDate` , wich select ?

Comment: What if max creation date for objectId Y is equals to creation date of objectId Z which is not max creation date of objectId Z?

Comment: @Rohit see forth line of query

Comment: FYI this runs several orders of magnitude slower than a native query using an inner join as used in the OP.

Comment: @Dave most times, native is faster than JPQL, but this question is about JPQL not about optimization.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani No - the question was specifically about "JPA Query: join a subquery with grouping condition" which is not possible in JPQL. So it becomes a choice _between_ JPQL and JPA Native Query (to permit a joined subquery). I was simply pointing out that the JPQL option performs horrendously and NOBODY should consider using it in production. The correct answer is to use a native query - which is still part of JPA.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM  Event
NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT object_id, MAX(creation_date) AS creation_date
    FROM Event
    GROUP BY object_id) groupedEvent
```

**if two equal max creation_date be in the same object_id**

```
SELECT ev.*
FROM Event ev
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT max(id) AS id
       FROM Event e
       INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT object_id, MAX(creation_date) AS last_date
               FROM Event GROUP BY object_id
              ) groupedEvent 
       ON e.object_id = groupedEvent.object_id
       AND e.creation_date = groupedEvent.last_date
       GROUP BY e.object_id) dist 
ON ev.id = dist.id;
```

```

Comment: Why does your `NATURAL JOIN` have an `ON` clause ??

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is not supported in JPA query language. Apart from that your query is similar to what I've already tried - it doesn't work.

Comment: @onedaywhen it's my fault , `NATURAL JOIN` no need `ON` condition

Comment: @Oleksandr Shpota sorry to helpless,other one should be work, can you provide more desc for  not work

Comment: I don’t remember exact error, but it just didn’t compile the query.